# Check string for a-z Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to verify if a string contains at least one character from a-z or A-Z. I have written this code to attempt to verify but if "dog" is entered into "strpassword" it still returns false. I am new at visual basic and sure I am missing something stupid.

```
        If strpassword Like "[*a-z]" Then
            lbloutput.Text = strpassword
            bolpasswordchk = True
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Password must contain a letter", "Input error")
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the wildcard character outside the bracket helps:

```
"*[a-z]"
```

But that only returns True if the password ends in lower-case letters.

To match "at least 1 character a - Z", you need:

```
"*[a-zA-Z]*"
```

This mean starting with zero or more characters (`*`), followed by an English letter (`[a-zA-Z]`), and ending with zero or more additional characters (`*`).

Comment: [a-Z] isn't a valid pattern for the Like operator. I think what you mean is `If strpassword Like "*[a-zA-Z]*" Then`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this in my earlier comment, but I believe the "?" should be removed, it is forcing there to be at least one character before the letter, so "d123" would be rejected.

Comment: Thanks Blackwood: Updated again. I had assumed it was more like standard RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to your problem is:

```
If strpassword.Any(Function(c) Char.IsLetter(c)) Then
    lbloutput.Text = strpassword
    bolpasswordchk = True
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Password must contain a letter", "Input error")
End If
```

With this you only check your assumption: "at least one character".
This solution does not use the VB only operator LIKE and let you focus on [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) learning.

Please remember to check null or empty strings if you use my solution.

@nunzabar answer is more suited to "from a-z or A-Z" problem, but with my solution you can accept non [ascii](/questions/tagged/ascii) letters.